# How to find resolution of an image in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, imagemagick

Is there a way to find a resolution for an image in OpenCV. I'm not looking for width and height, but the resolution.

I can find the resolution in ImageMagick like this:

`identify -format "%w x %h %x x %y" mypic.jpg
4175 x 4175 300 x 300%`

The resolution for the above image is `300`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098104/python-opencv2-cv2-wrapper-get-image-size

Comment: there is no way to do that with opencv. and resolution is a dtp thing, it's irrelevant in computer-vision.

Comment: As @berak says, the resolution is largely irrelevant until you actually come to lay down the pixels on a piece of paper or a screen. In computer vision, you just have so many pixels by so many pixels - and more is better (unless you are in a hurry) and that's what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit late, but you can use the `.shape` property of any image in OpenCV. So, here's some sample code to illustrate how use can use this.

```
#importing the module cv2
import cv2
#reading the image whose dimensions are to be found using imread() function
image = cv2.imread('input.jpg')
#using shape property to get the dimensions of the image
dimensions = image.shape
print(dimensions)
```

Hope this answers your question.