# Conditionnally assign pixel values of one image to another

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pixel, assign

I have two images ( of the same size): A and B

**A is the mask**, it contains regions that have zero value and others that have RGB values.

**B is the RGB image** that i want to change the values of some of its pixels to their correspondent A's pixels (pixels that have the same position and that are different from zero).

I think it would be something like this:

**if A(i,j) <>0 then B(i,j)=A(i,j)**

except that i don't know how to write it in python...
can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the images with `opencv`:

```
h = b.shape[0]
w = b.shape[1]
for y in range(0, h):
        for x in range(0, w):
            if a[y,x] > 0:
                b[y,x] = a[y,x]
```

Or better, as points @Dan Mašek in the comment

```
import numpy as np

def apply_mask(img, mask):
    img = np.where(mask > 0, mask, img)
    return img
```

Notice that in `numpy` arrays, the height comes first in shape. `Opencv` loads the image into `numpy` arrays.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm a newbie in opencv, what does h = b.shape[0] stand for?

Comment: Better choice would be [`np.where(a > 0, a, b)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead of all that code. Most likely at least order of magniture faster too.

Comment: so after loading the images, i write this line and it's all set?

Comment: @Black_panther you can find a detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19098258/744859)

Comment: I tried to type the code but it gave me this error: AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'imread_COLOR'

Answer (score 1):

To apply the `mask` for `src`, you can use `cv2.bitwise_and`:

```
cv2.bitwise_and(src, src, mask=mask)
```

Comment: That would be more general if you both use python and c++.